# How to find a record which best matches to given string using only mySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I am having a hard time figuring this one out so I came here for help.

I have a table *x_25_operators* which has a field called *mask*.
Masks are numbers with length between 7-11 digits. What I am trying to achieve here is to find the best match for my query at this particular table.

Given the scenario:

*x_25_operators*

```
| some_other_data | mask
         .          486737
         .          616724
         .          915776
```

I have a number: 48915776148 (this number is fixed-length, always 11 digits)

I am looking for a query which will return a row containing *mask* 915776 (or all rows fitting to this searched number as filtering best-matching-one out should be a piece of cake).

I was thinking of using *LIKE* as the filter but such query:

```
SELECT * FROM x_25_operators WHERE mask LIKE '48915776148'
```

returns an empty query (which should be kind of obvious).

I am using a mySQL database.

Any ideas how to tackle such problem? I am open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LOCATE()`

`SELECT * FROM x_25_operators WHERE LOCATE(mask , "48915776148")`

Here is some more info: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-locate-function.php

Comment: works perfectly! I didn't know about that LOCATE(). Thank you for your help :)